# What does a JS function's prototype property used for?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I understand javascript prototype inheritance through the `__proto__` property. However I notice that when I do `var f = function() {}` f will now have a `prototype` property in addition to the `__proto__` property. It would seem that `prototype` does not participate in property chaining.  What exactly *does* it do?

Comment: When you call the function as a constructor, the returned object's `__proto__` property refers to the `prototype` object of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets assigned as the prototype of objects created by using that function via the `new` keyword.

So for instance:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = 47;

var obj = new Foo();
alert(obj.bar); // alerts 47, via `obj`'s prototype
```

The reference between `obj` and the object assigned to `Foo.prototype` is a live one, and so adding further things to `Foo.prototype` will make them show up on `obj`'s prototype:

```
Foo.prototype.charlie = 62;
alert(obj.charlie); // alerts 62
```

Naturally, if you *replace* `Foo.prototype` (which I discourage), then you're pointing `Foo.prototype` at a different object. `obj` will still refer to the old one:

```
Foo.prototype = {delta: 77}; // Not recommended
alert(obj.delta); // alerts "undefined"
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/okeri4)

Regarding `__proto__`: `__proto__` is non-standard. Prior to [ECMAScript5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (which is just a year and a half old), there was *no* standard way to interact directly with an object's prototype, you could only assign them at object creation time, and only indirectly via a constructor function's `prototype` property. `__proto__` is a proprietary extension in some JavaScript engines (most notably Mozilla's SpiderMonkey, the engine in Firefox). It's not in any standard, and according to the ECMAScript committee, it won't be. (Instead, ECMAScript5 provides *functions* for interacting with an object's prototype.) [`__proto__` is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) by Mozilla.

Answer (score 4):

the `_proto_`  property is a property of an **instance** of an object (the object being, in this case, a function), it refers to prototype of the instance.  You should note that this property is non-standard and depreciated, use `Object.getPrototypeOf(ref)` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto

`prototype`, in contrast, is a property of a function declaration (not an instance), and is the prototype for all instances of the function. Check out the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

When you create a new instance of a function (using the `new` keyword), a function object is created, as defined by the `prototype`.  After it is instantiated (`var myNewObject = new Foo()`), a call to `Object.getPrototypeOf(myNewObject)` will return a reference to the prototype upon which the instance is based.

To sum it up: `__proto__` is what something IS, `prototype` is what something CAN BE (or might already be).

Comment: *"the `_proto_` property is a property of an instance of a function"* An instance of an *object* (which may or may not have been created by a function).

Comment: Fair enough, it is still non-standard :)

Comment: Yes. And deprecated, no less. ;-)